# Pipeline Order of Execution

Tags: azure-data-factory

Say I have an ADF with pipelines that look as follows:

[image]

Will State, Asset and BranchType all execute in parallel (depending on available resources)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
You could click the debug button. You will find these three activities will be in-progress at the same time.